# how can I fix "Invalid Content-Type:text/html. Is this an error message instead of a SOAP response?"

Tags: java, xml, web-services, soap

I have to create an soap request and it give me some errors after the creation of it.

```
com.sun.xml.internal.messaging.saaj.SOAPExceptionImpl: Invalid Content-Type:text/html. Is this an error message instead of a SOAP response?
at com.sun.xml.internal.messaging.saaj.soap.MessageImpl.identifyContentType(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.xml.internal.messaging.saaj.soap.MessageFactoryImpl.createMessage(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.xml.internal.messaging.saaj.client.p2p.HttpSOAPConnection.post(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.xml.internal.messaging.saaj.client.p2p.HttpSOAPConnection.call(Unknown Source)
at packageH.SoapCall.main(SoapCall.java:41)
```

This is the code:

```
    public static void main(String[] args){

    try {
        String xml="<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv=\"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/\" xmlns:bcc=\"http://www.huawei.com/bme/cbsinterface/bccustomizedservices\" xmlns:cbs=\"http://www.huawei.com/bme/cbsinterface/cbscommon\" xmlns:bcc1=\"http://www.huawei.com/bme/cbsinterface/bccommon\"><soapenv:Header/><soapenv:Body><bcc:QueryBalFuRequestMsg><RequestHeader><cbs:Version>1</cbs:Version><cbs:BusinessCode>GetAllBalances</cbs:BusinessCode><cbs:MessageSeq>896879678676778968</cbs:MessageSeq><cbs:AccessSecurity><cbs:LoginSystemCode>102</cbs:LoginSystemCode><cbs:Password>O2+SSm/iwzGMtKK7LP0WUi7UqvfMgB/bCebuArha6VM=&amp;lt;</cbs:Password></cbs:AccessSecurity></RequestHeader><QueryBalFuRequest><bcc:QueryObj><bcc:SubAccessCode><bcc1:PrimaryIdentity>550022002</bcc1:PrimaryIdentity></bcc:SubAccessCode></bcc:QueryObj><bcc:QueryTarget>0</bcc:QueryTarget></QueryBalFuRequest></bcc:QueryBalFuRequestMsg></soapenv:Body></soapenv:Envelope>";
        SOAPConnectionFactory soapConnectionFactory = SOAPConnectionFactory.newInstance();
        SOAPConnection soapConnection = soapConnectionFactory.createConnection();
        String serverURI = "http://localhost:8088/";
        String serverURI1="http://www.huawei.com/bme/cbsinterface/";
        MessageFactory messageFactory = MessageFactory.newInstance();
        SOAPMessage soapMessage =getSoapMessageFromString(xml);
        MimeHeaders headers = soapMessage.getMimeHeaders();
        headers.addHeader("SOAPAction", serverURI1  + "bccustomizedservices");
        headers.addHeader("SOAPAction", serverURI1  + "cbscommon");
        headers.addHeader("SOAPAction", serverURI1  + "bccommon");
        soapMessage.saveChanges();
        System.out.print("Request SOAP Message = ");
        soapMessage.writeTo(System.out);
        System.out.println();
        SOAPMessage soapResponse = soapConnection.call(soapMessage, serverURI);
        System.out.print("Request SOAP Message = ");
        soapMessage.writeTo(System.out);
        System.out.println("");
        TransformerFactory transformerFactory = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
        Transformer transformer = transformerFactory.newTransformer();
        Source sourceContent = soapResponse.getSOAPPart().getContent();
        System.out.print("\nResponse SOAP Message = ");
        StreamResult result = new StreamResult(System.out);
        transformer.transform(sourceContent, result);
        soapConnection.close();
    } catch (UnsupportedOperationException | SOAPException | IOException | TransformerException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}

private static SOAPMessage getSoapMessageFromString(String xml) throws SOAPException, IOException {
    MessageFactory factory = MessageFactory.newInstance();
    SOAPMessage message = factory.createMessage(new MimeHeaders(), new ByteArrayInputStream(xml.getBytes(Charset.forName("UTF-8"))));
    return message;
}
```

Comment: You need to find out what the response actually contains.  As the exception message hints, the response is probably an *error page*.  It may tell you what is wrong with the SOAP request you sent ... or where you sent it to.

Comment: sadly that is not the response from request because it goes until at SOAPMessage soapResponse = soapConnection.call(soapMessage, serverURI); and gives that error.

Comment: I think you misunderstood my comment.

Comment: well I understood your response and the answer isn't an error page because are some information and on error it should return "there is no answer". the problem is before the sending of message, because I checked already and on server side isn't make any call

Comment: Well ... the reason that the (SOAP) server side is not getting the call is probably that the call is going somewhere else ... and the somewhere else is saying "I don't understand" in HTML.   Have you actually **seen** the content that the exception is complaining about, or is this just conjecture on your part?